# Deconflict/deconfliction: scope, register, casual use?

Tags: word-usage, metaphors, euphemism, military

This is about the (historically [recent](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deconflict%2Cdeconfliction&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdeconflict%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeconfliction%3B%2Cc0)) use of *deconflict*/*deconfliction*. Out of the *Collins*, *AHDotEL*, *Cambridge*, *M.-Webster*, *Dictionary.com*, *Longman*, *TFD*, Etymonline and [*ODO*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/deconflict), only the last one has it<sup>1</sup>:

> deconflict
>
> [with object] *Military*
> Reduce the risk of collision between
> (aircraft, airborne weaponry, etc.) in an area by coordinating their
> movements.
>
> *The platoon deconflicts airspace during flight in the air traffic control chat room.*
>
> ***No longer satisfied merely to deconflict the activities of the several
> services, we now seek joint interdependence.***
>
> Derivatives
>
> deconfliction 
> <sup>1</sup> noun
>
> *The various airspaces required by the heavy-lift vehicle, the delivery vehicles, and the airdrop cargo itself all require
> deconfliction with other airspace users.*
>
> [ *Oxford Dictionaries Online* (ODO), fragments from the *deconflict* entry, my emphasis ]

Clearly there is no conflict between opposing forces so this is not about *deescalation* and such. But that one example in bold feels out of place, strictly speaking; the sentence could originate from the military but it's no longer about the risk of collision, if but metaphorically; it is about streamlining, focus, coordination, jurisdiction and vision etc. It could be used in the business too.

---

- In the *ODO* entry, the noun *deconfliction* is not labelled *Military* per se like the verb is; should I read in anything from that (i.e. that it's more casual/usual than the verb)?
- In terms of scope and register, can you use *deconflict(ion)* to describe business re-engineering, processes and such when there's overlap, or will people think you're ex-military if you use that? It is about *coordination* as per the definition; but is the meaning shifting towards, or being used for, *conflict settlement/resolution* casually (*my daughters had a fight, so I have to go and deconflict that*; instead of *settle* etc.)? Is the word an euphemism for *coordination*? Is it casual, natural (*de*-*conflict*-*ion*) and expressive English at this point?
- How do you generally distinguish *deconflict/deconfliction* from *coordination*, *(re)conciliation*, *exchange of information*, *shared jurisdiction acknowledgement*, or ultimately just *planning* ahead; is it the implied duties and/or the consequences of not deconflicting, which make this different?
- Is that verb a term frequently used in civil aviation i.e. is it for instance how a native speaker could describe in practical terms what *airport traffic control* is?

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> In Canada, *Termium* has indexed the [verb](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&srchtxt=DECONFLICT) in a very specific context: *Sea Operations(Military)*. They also have a specific application for [*deconfliction*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&srchtxt=DECONFLICTION), a process of jurisdictional disentanglement so to speak, related to *Security*. The latter use is similar indeed to the sentence emphasized in the following *ODO* quote.</sub>

Comment: Isn't it a ELU question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had never seen or heard this word before it surfaced in the context of eliminating the possibility of inadvertent conflict between Russian and US air forces in Syria.

I'd guess it's a military/civil aviation expression (they're basically the same thing here: most aviation folks get their training in the military).

It looks like a useful word if it maintains its current very narrow sense of coordinating to forestall the possibility of accidental conflict. But if the BizSpeak or pop culture folks pick it up it will probably degenerate into another buzzword for smoothing over actual conflicts, employed as high slang to distinguish the user as cooler than people who don't use it yet. A pity if that happens.

Comment: Hi, I wanted to thank you for your insight here as well as on ELU. I remember at some point I had a very insightful exchange with you in the comments about something. I admire such a command of language related topics and openness. A Happy New Year and best regards to you!